# How to this expression $a^6+a^4+a^2b^2+b^4-b^6\;?$

Tags: factoring

I'm trying to factor this expression but I can not, please can anyone help me? $a^6+a^4+a^2b^2+b^4-b^6$ ?

Comment: Factorize $a^6-b^6$ first.

Comment: What are you studying? Where did this question arise?

Answer (score 2):

You may use this $$(a^2)^3-(b^2)^3=(a^2-b^2)(a^4+a^2b^2+b^4)$$

Can you do the rest?